# How to redirect to router.base URL in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Let's say my nuxt app is running in a subfolder 'test'.

**nuxt.config.js:**

```
router: {
    base: '/test/'
}
```

That means my application runs on localhost:3000/test

Now, when I go to `localhost:3000/tes`, all i get is a 404 Error with the contents `Cannot GET /tes`

However, I want to redirect to /test, or show my own 404 page. But I couldn't figure out a way to handle that case.

I tried using a middleware, but that only worked for links within the subfolder.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an error layout for the 404 page

[Error page](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#error-page)

Or you can use middle to check the incoming URL and redirect them somewhere.

[Middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware#middleware-directory)

You can create your error layout (error.vue in layout folder) and when error it will show that page.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-if="error.statusCode === 404">Page not found</h1>
    <h1 v-else>An error occurred</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['error'],
    layout: 'error' // you can set a custom layout for the error page
  }
</script>
```

Link showing practically how to do that: [medium](https://mavrickmaster.medium.com/custom-error-pages-with-nuxt-js-3c70e6c51aff#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Create%20your%20custom%20error%20page&text=The%20nuxt%20docs%20outline%20that,is%20passed%20down%20through%20props.)

Comment: The middleware only handles anything within localhost:3000/test, but not localhost:3000/xyz or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed in the nuxt documentation:

**Using a Hook to router.base when not on root:**

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-hooks#redirect-to-routerbase-when-not-on-root

Comment: I tried that too but got error Reflect.has called on non-object, do you know why ?